# Remove dot after TLD

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this code and I need to remove dot (.) only after TLD

```
<?php
$url ='15rm-mo.hello.com.';

    $response = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z1-9-]/', '', $url);
    echo $response;

?>
```

here is the output: 15rm-mohellocom
What I need is this: 15rm-mohello.com removing dot at the end. I can add dot in the regex but both dot will be remove. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "15rm-mohello.com removing dot at the end." at the end or in the middle too?

Comment: Did you know that, strictly speaking, that trailing `.` is supposed to be there, it's just that for convenience it was made implied and therefore optional.

Comment: @Cheery just at the end. your tricks fix it thanks again :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo rtrim('15rm-mo.hello.com.', '.');
```

ps: "15rm-mohello.com removing dot at the end." so, just at the end or in the middle too?

Comment: +1 Don't need regex for this if only the period needs to be trimmed. Although, more specifically, `rtrim`.

Comment: @Josh          Thanks :) I just thought about it after the posting.

Answer (score 3):

You may just replace something like `\.$` with '', this will remove ANY `.` at end of giving string.